# Permission denied for setting postgis permissions

Tags: amazon-rds, postgis

I am currently connected to an aws rds instance and I want to load in outdb rasters into my database. I've already loaded the rasters in through raster2pgsql, but I still cannot query the rasters because I need the following two permissions:
SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = true;
SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers TO 'ENABLE_ALL';

Since I'm using an aws rds instance, I went to change these permissions in the parameter groups. However, I could only find "postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers" and not "postgis.enable_outdb_rasters". Has anyone found a way around this and set postgis.enable_outdb_rasters to true successfully?